# Wrapping quotes around a php id in XML

Tags: php

I've got this line of code:

```
$xml_output .= "\t<Event=" . $x . ">\n";
```

And it will output:

```
<Event=0>

<Event=1>

<Event=2>
```

etc etc through my loop.

I need it to output as this (with the quotes around the number):

```
<Event="0">

<Event="1">

<Event="2">
```

Any help, and I'm sure it's simple would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml_output .= "\t<Event=\"" . $x . "\">\n";
```

[PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To specify a literal backslash before a single quote, or at the end of the string , double it (\\). Note that attempting to escape any other character will print the backslash too.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I don't do much PHP, so a real help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$xml_output .= "\t<Event=\"" . $x . "\">\n";`

However, that is not valid xml.

Comment: yeah, i missed off the event id= bit. Fixed that npw. It's late, a schoolboy error

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_output .= "\t<Event=\"" . $x . "\">\n";
```

The slash escapes the quote for output. More information about double quoted strings can be found in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)